# Batch FOR /D /r Output parrent directory

Tags: batch-file, filesystems

I have the following batch script;

```
CD /d %searchFolder%
FOR /D /r %%G in ("?earch") DO Echo We found %%G
```

This returns the folder i was searching for. Although i want to know the parent directory path, not the path of the file-folder itself.
I was thinking about replacing %%G with something that did the trick.

Output with %GG:

```
C:\Drive\folderToBeSearched\Search
```

Result i want:

```
C:\Drive\folderToBeSearched
```

Comment: Could it be `%%~dpG`? However, as suggested by Magoo, an example of your current & desired output would help readers.

Comment: Alternatively, `@for /f delims^= %%g in ('dir /b/s/ad "%searchFolder%\search"')do @for %%h in ("%%~g\..")do @echo %%~fh`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick, using `%%~dpG` also had the backslach so i also had to remove that.

```
CD /d %searchFolder%
FOR /D /r %%G in ("?earch") DO set dir=%%~dpG

set dir=%dir:~0, -1%
```

Comment: You may therefore find that its worth performing a validation of the returned path, to prevent removing a trailing backslash, i.e. the root ```\``` of a directory, when defining your variable. If the resulting file would be in the root directory, add an additional suffixed backslash. This means when you subsequently remove the last character, your root location is not affected. For example: `DO IF "%%~dpG" == "%~dG\" (SET "dir=%%~dpG\") ELSE SET "dir=%%~dpG"`. So in the example of `D:\search`, `SET "dir=%dir:~0, -1%"`, would return ```D:\``` instead of `D:`.